# Install pakages (including Openshift Origin) on Fedora Atomic

Tags: fedora, container

After looking into various Openshift guides (for Fedora Atomic), I think I might be either missing the point of the Atomic Project, or doing something really wrong.

All guides tell me to run a `git clone`, or a `dnf install` or even a  `atomic-openshift-installer install` at some point, but none of those commands are available in Fedora Atomic.

How am I supposed to install software, or get the source code to build it myself ?

Just as an example, here are a few of the guides:

- [Installing an OpenShift Origin Cluster on Fedora 25 | Project Atomic](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/12/part1-install-origin-on-f25-atomic-host/)
- [Host Preparation - Installing a Cluster | OpenShift Origin](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/host_preparation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [First instruction](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/12/part1-install-origin-on-f25-atomic-host/) assume You do it from generic workstation, making installation on remote Atomic hosts. and assume at least ansible 2.2 and git already installed on management workstation.
- Second instruction to install OpenShift on RHEL.
- If you try install to atomic host using atomic host as management workstation, first install dependencies (ansible 2.2 and git) using `atomic host install`

I quick google [Differences between RHEL Server and RHEL Atomic Host](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2772861)

> RHEL Atomic Host does not include yum or any other package manager
>   because updates and rollbacks are performed transactionally with the
>   "atomic host” command.

and

> Using the atomic host install [rpms] command lets you install packages
>   that are not part of the original ostree.